# How to exactly set Google Motion Chart options?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am using Google Motion Chart for X and Y data over some time units (T), I don't want the time measurement to be year, day or week. I also want the duration to be exactly T time units. I couldn't find any useful information in Google documentation on setting all of the state features. For example could the `iconType` be anything other than `"BUBBLE"` ? or what are other options for `time` . I also tried Unique Color setting but it did not work.

Any useful resources that I might have missed on customizing motion chart?

```
     var chart = new google.visualization.MotionChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(
        data, 


        {

        "duration":158,

        "xZoomedDataMin":0,

        "dimensions":{"iconDimensions":[0.5 ,1   ]},

        "playDuration":158,

        "time":"notime","xLambda":1,

        "iconKeySettings":[],

        "uniColorForNonSelected":false,



        "yZoomedDataMin":0,



        "iconType":"BUBBLE",


        "nonSelectedAlpha":0.4,
        "xZoomedIn":false,
        "colorOption":"_UNIQUE_COLOR",
        "orderedByY":false,

        "sizeOption":"_UNISIZE",
        "xZoomedDataMax":2,
        "yZoomedIn":false,
        "orderedByX":false,
        "showTrails":false,
        "yZoomedDataMax":499,

        "yLambda":1,

        "width": 800, 
        "height":600 ,
        "showXScalePicker": false , 
        "showYScalePicker": false , 
        "showChartButtons": false , 
        "showSidePanel":false ,
        "xZoomedDataMax":158,
        "uniColorForNonSelected":true ,
        "sizeOption":"2" }


        );
```